# Permissions doesn't show when installing an app

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app on the app store and in the manifest file I have two permissions, but when I go to install the app on a phone or tablet it says the app doesn't require any special permissions. My manifest file is below. Why does it says there are no special permissions when there is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.howlinapps.battery.level"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.05" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.howlinapps.battery.level.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.howlinapps.battery.level.About"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.howlinapps.battery.level.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="MyService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Battery level service" >
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where's your ending </manifest> tag?

Comment: Added now, it was there just not showing up in the code.

Comment: I looked it up on the playstore and it showed both permissions on my computer. Is it during the install process that you don't see them?

Comment: Yes, when I click on install it says App permissions **Battery level** _does not require any special permissions._

Comment: hmmm... is there a dropdown below that of _other_ permissions?

Comment: No. I just checked it on my tab (4.3), my phone (4.1) and my fathers phone (2.3.5) and none of them ask. What I see when I press install -> http://i.imgur.com/PBRfOZW.png

Comment: what do you see after clicking continue?

Comment: It installs just fine, but as commonsware says it's probably just a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would turn out that way. I was trying to figure out if maybe those weren't considered "special" permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions show up on [the Play Store Web site](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.howlinapps.battery.level). They are not showing up in the Play Store app for some reason. So long as your app is working -- meaning that you are getting the permissions -- this would appear to be a bug in the Play Store app and, therefore, is not your problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks it looks that way all right. Yey to finding a bug in the Play store.

Comment: One could conclude Google wants everyone installing apps no matter how much spying they do. Permissions for deciding whether to install used to be there, now gone.